# How to continue a shell file after exiting tail -f?

Tags: bash, macos, tail

I have a simple shell script (on macOS and Linux) that launches a service, tails the log and should shut down the service when I exit the tail:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 startmyService.sh
 tail -f service.log
 stopmyService
```

When I exit tail either with `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-Z` the whole shell script stops. How can I exit `tail -f` and have the shell script continue with the next instruction?

Comment: Consider attaching `stopmyService` to an EXIT trap.

Comment: (You can also trap the SIGINT alone).

Comment: You could trap interrupt signal and restore it after tail `trap : int; tail -f service.log; trap - int`